# Separate Develop and Production files in npm or webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have seen in react native project, we use `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` to separate `index.js` file for android and ios.

Now is it possible for `develop` and `production` environment to separate their files ??
I mean does `webpack` or a plugin or maybe `node` have any ability to separate them like `index.develop.js` and `index.js` (for production) and require it like `require('index')` ?

Comment: Have you checked the corresponding section in [webpack docpage](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)?

Comment: Thanks, this link was really good, but didn't work for me. It just can change entry file. can not switch any file with post fix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, using `process.env.NODE_ENV` you can dynamically `require()`:

```
  const module = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" 
    ? require("./production")
     : require("./development");
```

Then if production mode is on, the comparison will be inlined, and the `require("./development")` will be optimized away.

Comment: is there any loader or plugin for webpack to do this automatically when sees both index.js and index.develop.js exists in a folder ??

Comment: I dunno, never had a usecase for this.